# regular expression to match string

Tags: regex

i want a pattern to match below strings :

```
count="2"
count = "2"
count   =    "2"
count='2'
count = '2'
count  =  '2'
count=2
count = 2
count   =   2
```

Comment: As I've mentioned, you could explain what *isn't* matched by the regex, and what language are you using - you'd definitely get better answers that way `:)`

Comment: i want get html attribute in php, have better idea ? :)

Comment: Actually, yes, there are much better ideas. Using an [html parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) may be much easier than a regex, and get better results.

Comment: because i want it for my template engine, i think regex is better than HTMLParser :-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't too clear what should the pattern *not* match, but you may be looking for something like this:

```
count\s*=\s*(["']?)\d+\1
```

That regex will allow matching quotes (or no quotes) around a number. `\1` matches the same thing the first captured group (`["']?`) matched before: `"`, `'`, or nothing, so it wouldn't allow mixed quotes. `(?:"\d+"|'\d+'|\d+)` would have worked similarly.

You may want a better definition of strings or numbers, for example:

```
count\s*=\s*(?:"(?:[^"\n\r\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\n\r\\]|\\.)*'|\d+)
```

The regex allows strings with escaped characters an no new-lines, or integer literals.

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you'd explain the grouping & back-reference :)

Comment: Thank you, i use from this : `count\s*=\s*(["\']?)([a-z0-9]+)\1` and work perfect for me, of course with your help ! ;)

Comment: +1 Good answer. I would just add that the efficiency (speed) of: `"(?:[^"\n\r\\]|\\.)*"` can be improved by _"[Unrolling-the-Loop](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "from: Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)")"_ like so: `"[^"\n\r\\]*(?:\\.[^"\n\r\\]*)*"`. The same enhancement can be applied to the single quoted expression. Note that this speed enhancement only applies to backtracking NFA engines - i.e. Javascript, Ruby, PHP, Perl, Python, .NET etc.